# Rails 3 Unobtrusive Javascript Search Form Back Button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

I am using unobtrusive javascript to render search results from a get request -- a search.

When a user follows a search result and doesn't like it they need to be able to hit back and get to the same results.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You should take a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/246-ajax-history-state. pjax: https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax also seems  interesting. However these both work on history api, so you might need to look for other js plugins as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [HTML5 History API](http://html5demos.com/history) for modern browsers to change the URL every time you change the application state, and you call fallback on changing the URL anchor tag when you want to capture a history state.  An example of the former is source code navigation in Github using [PJax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) and Twitter is the example of the latter.